# Certain properties of uniform structure

Tags: general-topology, filters, uniform-spaces

I am trying to read about unifrom spaces from [Introduction to Uniform Spaces](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/introduction-to-uniform-spaces/B45FBD3886A6BD8E4B5A6719E44D0477), and I was wondering about some basic facts which I wasn't able to find there. Let $(X,\mathcal{E})$ be a uniform space.

1. Can we find a base $\mathcal{B}$ for $\mathcal{E}$ such that $D\supseteq D^2$ for all $D\in \mathcal{B}$? I actually need to check whether we can say that $D[A]\supseteq D^2[A]$ for any set
   $A\subseteq X$.
2. This may be a trivial question, but can we say that $E^2\supseteq E$ for any $E\in \mathcal{E}$? I think this follows from the fact that $E\supseteq \Delta X$, but I am not sure.
3. If $\mathcal{E}$ is a left uniform structure on a topological group $G$, can we say that base entourages are of the form $U\times U$, where $U$ is a neighbourhood of $e\in G$?

Since I am trying to read this without prior experience, I would appreciate any relevant insights. Thanks to all responders.

Comment: Question 1 is unclear because you have $\supseteq$ in the first line and  $\subseteq$ in the second. You probably meant $\supseteq$ and then the answer is no.  For question 2, yes. For question 3, no because $U\times U$ will usually not include the diagonal.

Comment: @AndreasBlass You are right, I edited  it. About question $3$, is there a simple description of that sort $ \cup_{g\in G} gU\times gU$ for a base of entourages?

Comment: Yes, those unions give a base for the left uniformity.  (They're also the reason for the "left" terminology; the right uniformity would use $Ug$ instead of $gU$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the first is *no*, though **some** uniformities (the discrete one) this *can* indeed be done, taking $\{\Delta_X\}$ as that base. Maybe such a base implies that the uniformity is discrete, I haven't checked. But $D^2 \subseteq D$ is quite rare ( if $D$ were also symmetric, we’d have an equivalence relation as entourage)..

Of course (as to 2) we always have $E \subseteq E^2$ almost trivially: $(x,y) \in E$ then also $(y,y) \in E$ as $\Delta_X \subseteq E$ and so $(x,y) \in E^2$ by definition...

For 3 no: a standard base for the *left* uniformity is all sets of the form $$\bigcup_{g \in G} (gU \times gU)$$ where $U$ ranges over a neighbourhood base of $e$ in $G$. Such sets have at least the property that the contain $\Delta_G$, as they should, while $U \times U$ does not so cannot be an entourage at all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you think the weaker version of $1$ could hold? i.e., finding a base of entourages, $\mathcal{B}$,  such that $E^2[A]\subseteq E[A]$ for any $A\subseteq X$ and $E\in \mathcal{B}$?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur no I think that’s hopeless in general.

Comment: Okay, thanks again.